# Show notification until timeout unless hovered (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to build a notification system and I am starting with the UI/UX and I am starting to build a proof of concept but I am struggling with debugging my timeouts. Any help would be awesome.

**JavaScript:**

```
  //Remove notification after 5 seconds
  var timer;

  new function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      removeNotification($notification);
    }, 5000);
  }

  //If any notification is hovered then start the timer again
  jQuery("#notificationList").hover(function (){
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> `new Function() {..}` -> Declaring function in this way causes the function not to be compiled, and is potentially slower than the other ways of declaring functions.

So, have an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), like below.

```
//Remove notification after 5 seconds
var timer = false;

(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        removeNotification($notification);
    }, 5000);
}());
```

And change:

```
//If any notification is hovered then start the timer again
jQuery("#notificationList").hover(function (){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

To:

```
//If any notification is hovered then start the timer again
jQuery("#notificationList").hover(function () {
    removeNotification($notification);
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Since `clearTimeout` won't run if the timer was not initially set. Hope that helps.

Your entire code(as I couldn't fork your pen):

```
//Notification markup
var notificationMarkup = '<li class="notification"><a href="#"><span class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://www.guestsofdave.com/images/scarlett%20johansson.jpg"/></span><span class="message-wrapper"><span class="message"><span class="info"><strong>Scarlett</strong> has replied to your <strong>forum post</strong>.</span><span class="meta"><i class="application forum"></i> <span class="notification-date">1 Hour Ago</span></span></span></span></a><span class="close-db-notification"></span></li>';

//CSS animation end hook
var animationEnd = "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend";

//Remove notification function
function removeNotification($notification) {
    $notification.addClass("animated zoomOut");

    $notification.animate({
        height: 0
    }, 150, function() {
        $notification.remove();
    });
}

//New notification
jQuery(".new-notification").click(function() {

    //Gets the last notification added
    var $notification = jQuery("#notificationList .notification").last();

    //Append the notification markup into the list
    jQuery("#notificationList").append(notificationMarkup);

    //Animate the notifications height from 0 to 90px and then animate it in
    $notification.animate({
        height: 90
    }, 150, function() {
        jQuery(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        jQuery(this).addClass("animated zoomIn");
    });

    //Remove animation classes when animation ends
    $notification.on(animationEnd, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("animated zoomIn")
    });

    //Remove notification after 5 seconds
    var timer = false;

    (function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            removeNotification($notification);
        }, 5000);
    }());

    //If any notification is hovered then start the timer again
    jQuery("#notificationList").hover(function() {
        removeNotification($notification);
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});

//Remove notification on click
jQuery(document).on("click", ".close-db-notification", function() {
    var $notification = jQuery(this).closest(".notification");

    removeNotification($notification);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer although it seems that with that code when you hover it removes all the notifications at once, and I want the opposite to happen. I would like the notifications to all stay and clear the timeout until they are unhovered

Comment: Not very clear as to what you are after. Put in some more details as to what's expected. Do you want only the hovered panel to be removed and remove all/rest in 5 secs if none is hovered?

Comment: I want a notification to show for 5 seconds unless any notification is hovered. I am trying to mimic facebooks live notification UX